# How to catch the clipboard event (onChangeClipboard equivalent) from any application in Python

Tags: python, clipboard

I am working on a clipboard manager. My current issue is to succeed in catching modification of the clipboard from any applications. For instance :

- From a ctrl - c
- From a right click and copy to clipboard

The idea is that a python script is running in background, like a deamon and catch every change of the clipboard

Thank you a lot  :)

PS:
For people who know autohotkey, I am looking for onClipboardChange equivalent

Comment: what os? .... I doubt you can get an event you will probably have to use polling\

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found in the web a solution using GTK:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def callBack(*args):
    print("Clipboard changed. New value = " + clip.wait_for_text())

clip = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
clip.connect('owner-change', callBack)
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: For this to work on Windows, you need 1. Install Visual Studio (the Community edition is good enough) with the Windows SDK 2. Install the GTK library using `vcpkg` as explained [here](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php) 3. Run `pip install pygobject`

Answer (score 2):

Do this with C# / Mono and Gtk.

```
    /* put this eventhandler on your main method */
    Gtk.Clipboard.Get (Gdk.Selection.Clipboard).OwnerChange += onClipboardOwnerChange;

    protected void onClipboardOwnerChange (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          Console.WriteLine ("onClipboardOwnerChange!!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to poll the clipboard ... I dont think you can listen for an event

here is an example in windows

```
import win32clipboard
last_data = None
while True:
    # get clipboard data
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    if data != last_data:
       print "Clipboard Changed!" + data
       last_data = data
```

Comment: win32clipboard has SetClipboardViewer to set up a hook. It's somewhat buggy though.